# Adopting os_log APIs while keeping backward compatibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, logging, macros

I'm trying to add support for the new logging and activity tracing APIs to a library in a way that maintains backward compatibility for users of the library who haven't yet adopted the latest version of the OS (iOS or macOS). I'm defining custom logging macros for each level of logging, and then for older OSes, falling back to `NSLog`. I've gotten this working, with one problem.

The new APIs require you to mark any non-constant, non-scalar values as explicitly `public` if you want them to show up in log output. This is what an invocation of my macro looks like:

```
UZKLogInfo("Reading file %{public}@ from archive", fileName);
```

This compiles fine with the SDK that includes `os_log` (e.g. iOS 10.0 or later), but when I compile with an earlier version so my macro falls back to `NSLog`, I get a compiler warning:

> Using 'public' format specifier annotation outside of os_log()/os_trace()

And the log line printed looks like this:

```
Reading file <decode: missing data> from archive
```

This is a simplified version of my macro definition (only including the `info` definition and simplifying the conditional:

```
#if UNIFIED_LOGGING_SUPPORTED
    @import os.log;

    #define UZKLogInfo(format, ...) os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else // Fall back to regular NSLog
    #define UZKLogInfo(format, ...) NSLog(@format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#endif
```

Is there any way to strip the "{public}" text (some kind of string replacement?) from `format` in the fallback case? Or is there another way to support the old and new APIs without giving up the level of info I've always shown in the logs? I need to use a macro (according the [last year's WWDC session on the topic](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/), or else I lose the call site metadata.

Comment: "Some kind of string replacement" sounds like you have answered your own question. Have you looked at what methods `NSString` provides?

Comment: @CRD But what I want to do the replacement on isn't an `NSString`, it's text from the source file that gets placed into the macro – it's not an allocated object in memory. I'm not sure what facilities the preprocessor has available, but I don't think there's a way for me to make use of the methods on `NSString`.

Comment: Your `@format` is an `NSString`, it doesn't matter if the string is programmatically generated or a literal it is still an `NSString`. You may not be able to alter the string during compilation but you can alter it at runtime. Your macro includes a call to `NSLog`, it can include a method call.

Comment: @CRD Now I understand your suggestion, but I _was_ looking for a compile-time solution. I think adding `NSString` substitution can work as a last resort, though.

Comment: The compile time solution is to change the file extension on your code file, say to `.myExt`, and add a build rule in Xcode for `.myExt`. The build rule then processes the `.myExt` into a `.m` removing the unwanted occurrences of `{public}`, and the compiler then handles the `.m`. The build rule is a script which can call any command line app etc. to do its job. Apple has (used to have?) an example that used a Ruby script to preprocess strings files, you might be able to adapt it. Or you could just include the `NSString` method in your macro, runtime cost is probably insignificant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to do an `NSString` replace in the macro, and to suppress the compiler warnings as part of it, so it could be done for each line, rather than globally for the whole file or project. It looks like this:

```
#if UNIFIED_LOGGING_SUPPORTED
    @import os.log;

    #define UZKLogInfo(format, ...) os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);

#else // Fall back to regular NSLog

    #define _removeLogFormatTokens(format) [@format stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{public}" withString:@""]
    #define _stringify(a) #a
    #define _nsLogWithoutWarnings(format, ...) \
        _Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic push ) ) \
        _Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral" ) ) \
        _Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-security" ) ) \
        NSLog(_removeLogFormatTokens(format), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        _Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic pop ) )

    #define UZKLogInfo(format, ...) _nsLogWithoutWarnings(format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#endif
```

It's called like so:

```
UZKLogInfo("Message: %@", anObjectToLog);
```

Comment: I've been thinking about how to do this as well. Thanks for sharing. One thing I'm considering is doing the opposite - adding `{public}` to the log formats for iOS 10+ instead of removing for older versions. That way I don't have to find & replace on all the log statements I already have... none of our log data will be "private" as it is. We'll see how that goes.

Comment: I would be curious to see what your `#if UNIFIED_LOGGING_SUPPORTED` logic actually was, though. I don't know of a way to do this sort of check at compile time in a library, since the support is based on iOS version on the device, right?

Comment: @manroe Yeah, I'm grouping the OS versions of all platforms. You can see it here: https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit/commit/8cf48b84d4b674467e774f3d1844e4008fedc7ad#diff-9b62aea6b32c19c0cc4f2ac623b5d6a4R21

Comment: thanks for the link. I guess this works for you because the header you linked to is public, so the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 100000 ` is evaluated for the SDK users' app settings rather than your SDK build settings. and also, because you won't support os_log on iOS 10 devices if the app supports iOS 8. this is something that I want to do.